# No result update a custom field using wp_schedule_event

Tags: custom-field, hooks, facebook, wp-cron, automation

I recently developed a news blog. My client asked for a facebook share count of an article.

I am able to get the share count using facebook api, However, according to the information I found from various questions from here and there, facebook limits the number of API calls. So, i have decided to pull the share count information every hour then update every post share count information using a custom meta field. I used **wp_schedule_event** for automation. But, Some how the following code isn't working.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cb_fb_share_count_activation' );
function cb_fb_share_count_activation() {
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'cb_update_fb_share_count' );
    if( $timestamp == false ){
       wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'cb_update_fb_share_count' );
    }
}
add_action( 'cb_update_fb_share_count', 'cb_update_count' );
function cb_update_count(){
    $posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1) );
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $url = get_the_ID();
        $fbcount = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls='.$url.'&format=json' ));
        $fb_share_count = $fbcount[0]->share_count; 
        update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cb_fb_share_count', $fb_share_count);
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'cb_delete_fb_share_count_schedule' );
function cb_delete_fb_share_count_schedule() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'cb_update_fb_share_count' );
}
```

I then tried 'wp_footer' to test the get_posts and It's working. Whats wrong with the custom hook ? Where am I doing it wrong?

**P.S: I am aware that Wp-cron requires a page view to operate properly.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think that your problem is the you are passing the post ID as url parameter to facebook API:

```
$url = get_the_ID();
```

Also, as `get_posts` return an array of post objects, you could use this code:

```
$posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1) );
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $url = get_permalink( $post->ID );
    $fbcount = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls='.$url.'&format=json' ) );
    $fb_share_count = $fbcount[0]->share_count; 
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cb_fb_share_count', $fb_share_count );
}
```

I would go further and suggest to remove the checking of `wp_next_scheduled` in the activation action hook, it is not needed because at plugin activatition the scheduled event is supposed to not exists. And finally, I suggest to use [`wp_remote_get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) instead of `file_get_contents`, I think it is really better and have more control about the request:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cb_fb_share_count_activation' );
function cb_fb_share_count_activation() {

    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'cb_update_fb_share_count' );

}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'cb_delete_fb_share_count_schedule' );
function cb_delete_fb_share_count_schedule() {

    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'cb_update_fb_share_count' );

}

add_action( 'cb_update_fb_share_count', 'cb_update_count' );
function cb_update_count(){

    $posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1) );

    foreach($posts as $post) {

        $url = get_permalink( $post->ID );

        $response = wp_remote_get('https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls='.$url.'&format=json' );

        if( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {

            $fbcount = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );


            $fb_share_count = $fbcount[0]->share_count; 

            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cb_fb_share_count', $fb_share_count );

        } else {

            //Do something if it was an error comunicating with Facebook

        }

    }

}
```

PD: I think this is no very good approach. Get all posts and connect to Facebook one by one, all in the same WordPress load, can be very slow and intense.

Comment: Thank you so much :)...and then what could be a good approch?...can I use the_content filter instead of custom schedule hook?

Comment: I don't know what approach would be better, I would think about it. But yours I think is not. Imaging you have, lets say 1000 posts; in one single cron you get all of them, connect to facebook 1000 times and run update_post_meta 1000 times. It is very probably that most shared hosting and small VPS enviroment will crash or go over max time execution timeout.

Comment: Right now he just had 50 posts, may be 300 in next three months. I will post another question here. Thank you very much for solving my problem :)